# How to add context menu to a canvas element?

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu, java-canvas

**Problem :** It is not possible to simply 'add' ContextMenu to a Canvas or Pane element via addContextMenu(menu), which works only with javafx.scene.control elements (and neither Canvas or Panel extends this class).

**Question :** Is there any 'clean' way to 'register' ContextMenu item to a Canvas element? I expect standard behavior of this menu (to show after RMB clicked on Canvas element, autohide when clicked with LMB etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Canvas canvas = ... ;
ContextMenu menu = ... ;

canvas.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> menu.show(canvas, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));
```

Answer (score 0):

James_D's solution may not dismiss the menu when clicking the canvas while the context menu is visible. See this bug :

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095591

So instead, I suggest using :

```
Canvas canvas = ... ;
ContextMenu menu = ... ;

canvas.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> menu.show(canvas.getScene().getWindow(), e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use Chrome extension's contextMenu. here is [the official document.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#type-ContextType)

The only issue so far I find is that the Context type for a canvas is not clear. ["all"] works but is not a good way.

Comment: hmm .. never heard that chrome supports fx?